# Bind to DependencyProperty of child control in content control

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I want to show information of a *child control* of a ContentControl. The ContentControl finds the child control using caliburns view model binding as follows:

```
<ParentControl>
    <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding Path=CustomInput, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</ParentControl>
```

E.g. in the case where this custom input would bind to an `InputTextBoxView`, I want to show its info message in the parent control.

Something like

```
<ParentControl InfoMessage="{Binding RelativeSource to dependency property of MessageProperty in child element of ContentControl ....}">
    <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding Path=CustomInput, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</ParentControl>
```

Is this in any way possible?

Comment: Tried with {Binding PropertyName, ElementName=XXX} where XXX is the x:Name attribute value of the child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the `ContentControl` a `Name`, you can bind to a property of the `CustomInput` *model* using the `Content` property:

```
<ParentControl InfoMessage="{Binding Content.ModelProperty, ElementName=cc}">
    <ContentControl x:Name="cc" cal:View.Model="{Binding Path=CustomInput, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</ParentControl>
```

...but you cannot bind to a property of the resolved *view* for `CustomInput`.

Comment: hey thanks. Yeah was looking exactly for the latter :). I'll have to revisit the whole component I guess, this trivial requirement doesn't really fit in the way it's designed. Thanks for the info!